# How does $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x \ln (\sin x)~ dx $ converge to $\ln(2/e)?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I can solve this integral, 
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x \ln (\sin x)~ dx $$
by parts as
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x \ln (\sin x) dx=\left (\cos x +\ln \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)- \cos x \ln (\sin x) \right)_{0}^{\pi/2}=-1,$$ as the divergent parts  $\pm \infty$ cancel out. But Mathematica gives $I=\ln(2/e).$ How to resolve this?

Comment: Just as a side note: one could also invoke the [polar form of the Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties), aswell as the derivatives of the latter one, in order to compute a closed-form not relying on IBP. But this might be a little bit to much for this simple problem even though the machinery of the Beta Function (and the Gamma Function respectively) is quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an exact calculation of the indeterminate part of your solution.  My concern with the answer above is that it's not obvious (at least, not to me) that the approximations are good enough to justify the first equality.

First, use double-angle formulas and the property of logarithms to get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} [\cos x \ln(\sin x)-\ln(\tan \frac x2)]\\= \lim_{x \to 0^+}[\cos x(\ln 2 + \ln (\sin \frac x2) + \ln (\cos \frac x2))-\ln (\sin \frac x2)+\ln (\cos \frac x2)].$$

We can evaluate many of these terms immediately, leaving:

$$\ln 2 + \lim_{x \to 0^+}(\cos x -1)\ln (\sin \frac x2).$$

To evaluate this limit, we convert it to a form suitable for the use of L'Hopital's Rule and eliminate another term we can evaluate immediately:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln(\sin \frac x2)}{\frac{1}{\cos x -1}}= \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{\cos \frac x2}{2 \sin \frac x2}}{\frac{\sin x}{(\cos x -1)^2}}= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{(\cos x - 1)^2}{2\sin \frac x2 \sin x}.$$

Now we use double-angle formulas again:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{(\cos x - 1)^2}{2\sin \frac x2 \sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{4 \sin^4 \frac x2}{4\sin^2 \frac x2 \cos \frac x2}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin^2 \frac x2}{\cos \frac x2}=0.$$

Thus, the difference of the indeterminate forms is $\ln 2$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\infty -\infty$ is indeterminate it may or may not be zero.

Therefore, here you have to  take limit as $x\rightarrow 0^+$. Near zero $\tan x \sim x, \sin x \sim x$ and $\cos x\sim (1-x^2/2)$, then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \ln \tan (x/2)- \cos x \ln \sin x =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \ln (x/2)-(1-x^2/2) \ln x
=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \left( -\ln 2+(x^2/2) \ln x \right)=-\ln 2.$$ Then $I=-1+\ln 2=\ln(2/e)$.

Comment: How do you know that the approximations you're using are sufficiently good to justify your first equality?

Comment: aren't those from their respective taylor expansion at 0?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you may not be seeking this, but you can find the exact value for the integral using the Beta and by extension Gamma Function and it's derivative.

Here we will to address your integral:
\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x)\ln\left|\sin(x) \right|\:dx
\end{equation}
Here we will approach this integral by considering a general form:
\begin{equation}
 J_{n,m}(a,b) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^n\left|\sin(x) \right| \ln^m\left|\cos(x)\right|\sin^a(x)\cos^b(x)\:dx
\end{equation}
Where $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n,m \geq 0$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. We observe that $I = J_{1,0}(1,0)$. From here we employ the property:
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \left[ \sin^c(x) \right]= \ln\left|\sin(x)\right| \sin^c(x) \Longrightarrow \frac{\partial^n}{\partial c^n} \left[ \sin^c(x) \right]= \ln^n\left|\sin(x)\right| \sin^c(x)  
\end{align}
And so:
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{c \rightarrow a} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial c^n} \left[ \sin^c(x) \right] = \ln^n\left|\sin(x) \right|\sin^a(x)
\end{equation}
Similarly:
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{d \rightarrow b}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial b^m} \left[ \cos^b(x) \right]= \ln^m\left|\cos(x)\right| \cos^b(x)
\end{equation}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
J_{n,m}(a,b)&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^n\left|\sin(x) \right| \ln^m\left|\cos(x)\right|\sin^a(x)\cos^b(x)\:dx \nonumber \\
& = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \lim_{c \rightarrow a} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial c^n} \left[ \sin^c(x) \right] \lim_{d \rightarrow b}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial b^m} \left[ \cos^b(x) \right]\:dx
\end{align}
Employing Leibniz's Integral Rule and the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we can draw the partial derivatives and limits outside of the integrand:
\begin{align}
J_{n,m}(a,b) &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\lim_{c \rightarrow a} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial c^n} \left[ \sin^c(x) \right] \lim_{d \rightarrow b}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial b^m} \left[ \cos^b(x) \right]\:dx \nonumber \\
& = \lim_{c \rightarrow a} \lim_{d \rightarrow b} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial c^n} \frac{\partial^m}{\partial d^m} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^c(x)\cos^d(x)\:dx \nonumber \\
&= \lim_{(c,d)\rightarrow (a,b)}\frac{\partial^{n+m}}{\partial c^n \partial d^m} \left[ \frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{c + 1}{2}, \frac{d + 1}{2} \right) \right] 
\end{align}
Where $B(x,y)$ is the Beta Function. Employing the relationship between the Beta and Gamma Function this becomes:
\begin{align}
J_{n,m}(a,b) &= \frac{1}{2}  \lim_{(c,d)\rightarrow (a,b)}\frac{\partial^{n+m}}{\partial c^n \partial d^m} \left[ \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{c + 1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left( \frac{d + 1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{c + d}{2} + 1\right)} \right] 
\end{align}
Returning to your integral $I$:
\begin{align}
I &= J_{1,0}(1,0) = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{(c,d)\rightarrow (1,0)} \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \left[ \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{c + 1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left( \frac{d + 1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{c + d}{2} + 1\right)} \right] \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{(c,d)\rightarrow (1,0)} \Gamma\left(\frac{d + 1}{2}\right)\left[\frac{\Gamma^{'}\left( \frac{c + 1}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{c + d}{2} + 1\right)} -\frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{c + 1}{2}\right) \Gamma^{'}\left( \frac{c + d}{2} + 1\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{c + d}{2} + 1\right)}  \right] \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\left[ \frac{\Gamma^{'}\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)} - \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma^{'}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)} \right]
\end{align}
Now:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = \sqrt{\pi}, \quad \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \quad \Gamma^{'}\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = \sqrt{\pi}\left( - \gamma - 2\ln(2)\right),\quad \Gamma^{'}\left(\frac{3}{2} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(2 - \gamma - 2\ln(2)\right)
\end{equation}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
 I & \frac{1}{4} \cdot \sqrt{\pi}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left( - \gamma - 2\ln(2)\right)}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(2 - \gamma - 2\ln(2)\right)}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \right)^2}\right] \nonumber \\
& = \ln(2) - 1 = \ln\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using methods found here https://scientia.mat.utfsm.cl/archivos/vol32/5.pdf, we can find a recurrence relation for the general  sine-log-sine integral,
$$I_{m,n}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2m} x \log^n (\sin x)\ dx$$
$$I_{m,n+1}=-\log(2)I_{m,n}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\overline{H}_{2m}^{(k+1)}n!}{(n-k)!}I_{m,n-k}-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\frac{\zeta(k+1)n!}{(n-k)!}I_{m,n-k}$$
where $\overline{H}_{m}^{(n)}$ is the $n$th generalized skew-harmonic number.

---

Define the exponential generating function $G(t)$,
$$\begin{align*}G(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n}}{n!}t^n&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m}x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(t\log(\sin x))^n}{n!}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m+t}x\ dx \end{align*}$$
where upon using the integral representation of the Beta function,
$$G(t)=\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{t+1}{2}+m,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{t+1}{2}+m\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{t+2}{2}+m\right)}\tag{1}$$
now by Legendre's duplication formula,
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{t+1}{2}+m\right)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2^{2m+t}}\frac{\Gamma\left(t+2m+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{t+2}{2}+m\right)}$$
applying this to $(1)$,
$$G(t)=\frac{\pi}{2^{2m+t+1}}\frac{\Gamma(t+2m+1)}{\Gamma^2\left(\dfrac{t+2}{2}+m\right)}$$
taking the logarithmic derivative,
$$\frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}=-\log(2)+\psi(t+2m+1)-\psi\left(\frac{t+2}{2}+m\right).\tag{2}$$
Recall that  the Digamma function satisfies the difference equation,
$$\psi(z+n)-\psi(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{z+k},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
taking $z=t,n=2m+1$ for the first and $z=t/2,n=m+1$ for the second digamma function in $(2)$ respectively,
$$\frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}=-\log(2)+\psi(t+1)-\psi\left(\frac{t}{2}+1\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{1}{t+k}-2\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{t+2k}\tag{3}$$
where we also wrote out the $k=0$ term. Note that here,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{1}{t+k}-2\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{t+2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{t+2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{t+2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{t+k}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-t}{k}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-t)^n\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\overline{H}^{(n+1)}_{2m}t^n$$
where $\overline{H}_{m}^{(n)}$ is the $n$th generalized skew-harmonic number. Substituting this along with the $t$-expansion of the difference between two digamma functions in $(3)$,
$$\frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}=-\log(2)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\zeta(n+1)t^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\overline{H}^{(n+1)}_{2m}t^n$$
multiplying by $G(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n}}{n!}t^n$ on both sides and rearranging,
$$\begin{align*}G'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n+1}}{n!}t^n=&-\log(2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n}}{n!}t^n+\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n}}{n!}t^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\overline{H}_{2m}^{(n+1)}t^n\right)\\
&-\frac{1}{t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n-1}}{(n-1)!}t^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\zeta(n+1)t^n\right)\end{align*}$$ employing the Cauchy product,
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n+1}}{n!}t^n=&-\log(2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n}}{n!}t^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{\overline{H}_{2m}^{(k+1)}n!I_{m,n-k}}{(n-k)!}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!} \\
&-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\frac{\zeta(k+1)n!I_{m,n-k}}{(n-k)!}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}
\end{align*}$$
letting all sums start at $n=1$,
$$\begin{align*}\color{red}{I_{m,1}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n+1}}{n!}t^n=&\color{red}{-\log(2)I_{m,0}}-\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{I_{m,n}}{n!}t^n\\&+\color{red}{\overline{H}_{2m}I_{m,0}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{\overline{H}_{2m}^{(k+1)}n!I_{m,n-k}}{(n-k)!}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!} \\
&-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\frac{\zeta(k+1)n!I_{m,n-k}}{(n-k)!}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}.
\end{align*}\tag{4}$$
since,
$$I_{m,0}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m}x\ dx=\frac{\pi}{2^{2m+1}}\binom{2m}{m} \\I_{m,1}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m}x\log(\sin x)\ dx=\frac{\pi}{2^{2m+1}}\binom{2m}{m}\left(\overline{H}_{2m}-\log(2)\right)$$
we see the red terms in $(4)$ cancel out and by comparing coefficients of $t^n/n!$ we obtain the recurrence relation,
$$\boxed{I_{m,n+1}=-\log(2)I_{m,n}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\overline{H}_{2m}^{(k+1)}n!}{(n-k)!}I_{m,n-k}-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\frac{\zeta(k+1)n!}{(n-k)!}I_{m,n-k}}$$ subject to the two initial conditions given above.